# remove rectangle bracket from array and and print data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

[image]I am facing problem in print the array data and i want to remove rectangle bracket [] from array

1  - please remove rectangle bracket [] from array

2  - print resource_name from array

```
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    grades:'',
    slot:[],
      }
    }
 handleChange = date => {
         var slots = [];
          var date = new Date(date);
          var mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
          var ddd =  [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
          
            fetch('URL?date=' + ddd + '&class_type=trial&grade_id=' + this.state.grade_id + '', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                    var dd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
                     var ff = res.result.afternoon;
                         for(var i = 0; i < ff.length; i++)
                          {
                       var fff = (ff[i]);
                            }
                     slots.push(fff);   
                    }).catch(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false })); 
        
        console.log(slots);
        this.setState({ slot: slots });
        };


 **in  (this.state.slot)  i am getting give below array data**


 
     []
0: {resource_name: "Facilitator", resource_id: "50f7a1bf-b78b-4ead-9e11-918a9f337db2", resource_email: "gameghoster020@gmail.com", created_at: "2020-06-16T18:03:48+0530", updated_at: "2020-06-16T18:03:48+0530", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Could you please write more description of your problem?  I am not sure if you don't want to print data as array ?

Comment: That's the way developer tools works, is for you to know that what you're printing is an array, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ludwiguer  so i am asking here

Comment: You can't remove the brackets since is a visual aid from developer tools, it doesn't exists inside your object, if you want to print only resource_name, do this `console.log(this.state.slot[0].resurce_name)`

Comment: As stated by others, this is because its an array, dev tools is just making you aware of it. if you only want the resource_name you can do it for entry `[0]` as stated by ludwiguer. But probably best to work inside of a loop for the item.

Comment: @ludwiguer   giving error      TypeError: Cannot read property 'resurce_name' of undefined

Comment: It gave an error because `this.state.slot` is an empty array before fetching data. add condition like `if (this.state.slot && this.state.slot.lenght > 0) {console.log(this.state.slot[0].resurce_name)}`